# Cross environment web.config encryption using aspnet_iisreg

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, encryption, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application. and i am calling a 3rd party API from my server side using security token generated by the 3rd party application.
now i am passing the token in a secure manner as follow:-

- i am adding the token to the http header.
- and we are using https to communicate with the 3rd party system.

so i think the token can not be hacked during its transmission. but the problem i am facing is how i can store and read the token itself. currently i am storing this inside our `web.config` section:-

```
<appSettings>

.....    
.....
    <add key="SecureToken" value="12345" />
.....
.....
</appSettings>
```

and i am retrieving the value inside my application as follow:-

```
string Token = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecureToken"]
```

so  the security problem i am facing is that if someone access the live server he can read the `web.config` file and get the secure token. so i read that i can encrypt part of  the web.config sections using `aspnet_iisreg` command. but now i am not sure how i can force this to work across my environments? i mean where i need to run the `aspnet_iisreg` inside one environemnt let say the Dev ? or i need to run this command on the three environments  seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should run through a deployment script, it can be a msi or powershell or something else. If you deploy manually, it requires aspnet_regiis -pe "yourappsettings" -app ... which is also a manual job and error prone. So develop a package with all your pages, dlls, .js, images etc. and install that package (msi or powershell or something else) and install that to your server. In that package include a script which does aspnet_regiis command and this command should run after virtual directory creation, mainly it should be kinds of last action. If you are using powershell, it's a set of instructions - so one instruction should be aspnet_regiis command. Try with post build event for VS web deployment package.

Comment: can you adivce more on this ? i deploy my website using VS web deployment package ...

Comment: so you mean i can do the following; generate a web deployment package using VS from my Dev environment. then i can deploy the deployment package inside our live server's IIS. after that i can add the live secure token to the web.config. so in this case i should have everything working well, except that the token is stored un-securly inside the web.config. so i can run the aspnet_regiis on the live server , which will encrypt the web.config section containing the secure token ,, is this correct ? i can do the same on our staging server where i will run the aspnet_regiis ...

Comment: That's one way of doing, but avoid manual intervention if possible,  follow couple of steps more like a key container as a xml file with the required key that can be used to encrypt/decrypt the data in servers and delete xml file once script execution is done. Write a script file with required command including deletion of xml and execute in a post build event. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/877258/How-to-Encrypt-Web-config-Using-aspnet-regiis-exe This url shows encryption in a webfarm scenario,you may or may not need webfarm but the concept will definitely help to take a better decision.